# Can't convert string to int in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, type-conversion

I'm attempting to convert a string to an integer using PowerShell. However, it keeps on telling me that I don't have a valid number, even though I'm sure I do.

First of all, here's how I'm getting my variable, and a printout of the type, etc. just to ensure validity:

```
$obj = (New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    LastSaved = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 155).toString().trim()
})
Write-Host $obj.LastSaved
$datePart,$b,$c = $obj.LastSaved.Split(" ")
Write-Host $datePart
$intVar,$b,$c = $datePart.Split("/")
$intVar = $intVar.Trim()
$intVar -replace '\W', ''
Write-Host $intVar
Write-Host $intVar.GetType()
```

The output:

> 5/‎26/‎2016 ‏‎8:09 AM
>
> 5/26/2016
>
> 5
>
> System.String

Here's the first method I've tried for conversion:

```
[int]$converted = 0
[int]::TryParse($intVar, [ref]$converted)
Write-Host $converted
```

And the output:

> False
>
> 0

Next method:

```
$converted = [convert]::ToInt32($intVar, 10)
```

And the result:

> Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find any recognizable digits."

And the third method I've tried:

```
$converted = $intVar / 1
```

And the result:

> Cannot convert value "‎5" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

If I manually assign `$intVar` a value of "5" (`$intVar = "5"`) everything works just fine, so I think there must be an issue with how I'm getting the value. But I have no idea what I could be doing wrong, as the `GetType()` says it is indeed a string.

**EDIT:** Per TobyU's answer, I've also tried `$intVar = [int]$intVar`, with the same result of

> Cannot convert value "‎5" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

**EDIT:** Yet another method:

`$intVar = [int]::Parse($intVar)`

Which gives:

> Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

**EDIT 3:** So apparently, as some commenters mentioned, there are invalid characters. Here is the output of a `Format-Hex`:

```
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   3F 32 36                                         ?26
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `.Trim()` on your string to remove any possible hidden characters before/after the integer.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I've updated my code to try a `.Trim()` and `-replace`, with the same results (see my edit).

Comment: try sending it to `Format-Hex` to see what all is there. as others have mentioned, there is apparently _something_ there that otta not be.

Comment: also consider trying `-replace '[^\d]'` (the second parameter is optional if you're just deleting)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Ah, I didn't know about that method. I've updated the question with the hex output.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey - you are welcome! that cmdlet is a lovely way to find "invisible" characters. it looks like mklement0 has pointed out both the problem AND the fix. great! [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examining the error messages in your question's source text reveals that **your string contains the invisible [LEFT-TO-RIGHT-MARK Unicode character (`U+200E`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm)**, which is why the conversion fails.

Removing that character will make the conversion succeed, which in the simplest case is achieved by simply eliminating all non-digit chars. from the string:

```
# Simulate the input string with the invisible control char.
$intStr = [char] 0x200e + '5'

# FAILS, due to the invisible Unicode char.
[int] $intStr # -> ... "Input string was not in a correct format."

# OK - eliminate non-digits first.
# Note the required (...) for proper precedence.
[int] ($intStr -replace '\D') # -> 5
```

---

**Optional reading: Examining a string's characters:**

```
# Print the code points of the string's characters:
PS> [int[]] [char[]] $intStr
8206  # decimal equivalent of 0x200e, the LEFT-TO-RIGHT-MARK
53    # decimal equivalent of 0x54, the DIGIT FIVE

# Show the code points in hex. format and print the char.
PS> [char[]] $intStr | 
       Select-Object @{ n='CodePoint'; e={ 'U+{0}' -f ([int] $_).ToString('X4') } }, 
                     @{ n='Char';      e={ $_ } }

CodePoint Char
--------- ----
U+200E       ‎
U+0035       5
```

You can also use `Format-Hex`, but the format isn't easy to parse visually:

```
PS> $intStr | Format-Hex -Encoding BigEndianUnicode

                       00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
00000000000000000000   20 0E 00 35                                       ..5
```

`-Encoding BigEndianUnicode` (UTF16-BE) is used - even though .NET string use `Unicode` (UTF16-LE) - so that the invariably *byte*-oriented display shows the high byte of the 16-bit code units first, which reads more naturally.

Byte pair `20 0E` is the first code unit, `U+200E` (the left-to-right mark), and `00 35` the second one, `U+0035` (the digit `5`).

The printed characters to the right are of limited usefulness, because they are the *byte*-individual interpretation of the input bytes, which only renders characters in the 8-bit range as expected (code points <= `U+00FF`); a `0x0` byte is represented as a `.`

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey :) My pleasure; please see my update re examining a string's characters.

Comment: My goto for calculated properties is using `@( @{ ... } )` with each hashtable on a newline.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That gives you a lot of flexibility and allows you to omit the `,` between the elements (assuming you put them on separate lines), but my preference is to do without the enclosing `@( ... )` and use `,` to terminate each element line for implicit line continuation - as now shown in the answer. (An individual hashtable can be spread across multiple lines either way).

Answer (score 0):

```
$intVar = [int]$intVar
```

should work just fine in this case.

```
$intVar.GetType() # String
$intVar = [int]$intVar
$intVar.GetType() # Int32
```

Comment: This also gives me the error `Cannot convert value "‎5" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."`

Comment: Looks like there is a hidden character somewhere in your value.

Comment: I've updated my code to try a `.Trim()` and `-replace`, with the same results (see my edit)