# DateTime Error when reading file metadata

Tags: powershell, datetime

I'm trying to write some PowerShell code to sort photos & other media files.  The modified/created date of the file is not always accurate, so I'm reading the meta data of the file.  This I have successfully done and extracted the created date.  BUT I can't get PowerShell to recognize the string as a date.

What I WANT is to be able to re-order the date into year-month-date format, in this fashion:

```
$metaDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

But I don't believe metaDate is of the date type, it's a string.

So I'm attempting to use this code to convert the string to a date:

```
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($metaDate,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",$null)
```

However it keeps returning this error:

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

The date 'appears' to be a normal string when the variable is written into the console:

```
26/‎10/‎2017 ‏‎18:23
```

But checking the length returns 21 - i only see 16 characters (if you count the space)

gettype() returns:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Trimming makes no difference

Anyone have any ideas or experience working with PowerShell & file meta-data?  Can there be hidden characters in this string?

Note that manually entering the same string of characters into the ParseExact command WORKS (and the length returns 16), so there is something iffy about the string/variable I'm getting out of the file.

many thanks
Daz

Comment: I'd check what `$metaDate | Format-Hex` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can there be hidden characters in this string?

Indeed, your date string stored in `$metaDate` contains [invisible control characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), namely (`U+200E`([LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e))) and (`U+200F`([RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f))).
Use `-replace '\p{Cf}'` to remove them:

```
 $date=[datetime]::ParseExact($metaDate -replace '\p{Cf}', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', $null)
```

To visualize all characters in a string, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55006669/45375).

Comment: Glad to hear it, @DazAuto.